# When doing HIIT, how long should your intervals be?

Tags: cardio, hiit, tabata

I currently do a 1:2 ratio of high to low intensity. My high intensity interval lasts 60 seconds, and my low intensity one lasts 120 seconds. I do this on either the elliptical or the heavy bag (I'm forced to shorten the intervals on the heavy bag due to the large amount of energy exerted).

I know that over time, you should increase the ratio until you hit 2:1 high to low, which is generally agreed to be the sweet spot for HIIT.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how long the intervals should be. I've seen suggestions as low as 20:10 seconds (known as *Tabata*) or as high as 120:60 seconds (intervals higher than that don't appear to be considered HIIT). Is the length of the interval simply not as important as the ratio?

Answer (score 2):

**Long enough that you're pushing against your limits, short enough that you're doing it the whole time.**

If you find yourself feeling/thinking at the end of a high intensity inveral "hey, I could have gone on a little longer!", then it's too short. Same if, at the end of the last interval, you're not *thoroughly* exhausted.

On the other hand, if you you find that you're pacing yourself or slackening towards the end of an interval, i.e. you can't keep it at full intensity throughout, then it's too long.

Answer (score -1):

Don't focus on the specific ratios; *they don't matter much.* As long as the ratio is in favor of the high intensity exercises, you have little to worry about. 
 
Your goal is to keep ***increasing the duration of the high intensity per exercise.*** This strengthens your stamina, endurance, heart, and lungs. *Of course, it also burns calories like crazy!* 
 
The 20:10 ratio is too low for a reachable goal. Many exercises in P90X and Insanity videos use 60:30 seconds ratio; this is because the whole video lasts between 45 mins and 60 mins. Depending on the total time allotted for the exercises, you might want to aim for 120:45 seconds ratio *(yes, it's tough, but that's why it's a goal :))* 
 
The length of the interval is much more important than the ratios. The calories you'll burn *(and all the benefits you'll derive from the program)* depend on how much time *(and the intensity)* you apply to them; the ratio's simply a way to measure if you're improving or not. A 30:60 ratio indicates that you aren't pushing yourself enough *(indicating your body needs more strength and stamina)*. *However, as long as you're getting up there and giving it your best, that's great and the numbers will improve.* 
 
Oh, one more thing: **keep being awesome through exercises.** :)

Comment: "increasing the duration of the high intensity per exercise" makes perfect sense...but it's also in disagreement of the popular "Tabata" routine which uses 20 seconds of high intensity and 10 seconds of rest. It's difficult to figure out whether the longer intervals are better than the short ones, but perhaps it's a matter of "to each his own".

Comment: @TonyArra I'm not aware of Tabata routine; however, 20 seconds high intensity is for beginners; as you become fitter, you'll realize you aren't getting much bang for your buck. Also, 10 seconds rest is too small. I doubt that many people who rest that short a duration will be able to perform better in the next exercises. I recommend a minimum of 30 seconds low intensity/rest *(10 seconds to catch your breath, 20 seconds to deep breath)* . I know that Insanity and P90X videos use similar durations too :). *More importantly, you want to challenge your body, not stick to a routine.* :)

Comment: I am aware of the Tabata training.  For tabata, 20-40 seconds max due to the strictness of the recovery and the type of exercise selected/ number of repeats etc. For standard interval you can work for longer, but obviously the recovery would be longer.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD The difference with the Tabata routine is that it was actually tested in a medical experiment (by a doctor Tabata, in fact), so we know it works. The 20/10 interval (you do 8 of them generally) is enough bang for the buck if you choose a difficult enough exercise. In the end, you should just tune your intervals to the demand of your sport (eg. if you're boxing, then 2min/1min or whatever) -- if you don't have a particular sport, then might as well Tabata.

Comment: @VPeric Granted that P90X and Insanity weren't developed in a lab; however, the results they generate *(amongst the millions who have used them)* prove that it works as well *(without having a particular sport)* . If your goal of cardio is to increase endurance and stamina, you won't accomplish that with a 20:10 seconds. *Either you'll cheat or you'll realize it doesn't help you after a couple of months.* To regain your energy after a high intensity training, you need to breath deep slowly. Catching your breath and doing that will take more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @VPeric Moreover, 20 seconds is too small for 15 pullups/chinups, 30-rep knee jumps, 25 seconds plank, 15-rep push ups, or even sprinting. And these are beginner exercises. You'll no doubt wear yourself out faster. More importantly, ask yourself: who will have more stamina: **the guy doing 120:30 seconds or the one doing 20:10 seconds?** *At the end of the day, you can't beat the efficacy of results.* :)

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD If you wish, we can continue this discussion in the chat, though I fail to see the point (you also contradict yourself slightly in the first comment). In the end, specificity of training will always win over, which is what I said in my original comment. When I did Tabata (burpees), my goal was to increase my VO2max, which it handled surprisingly well. Your mileage may vary. I'm not against P90X or whatever.

Comment: @VPeric I'm not saying Tabata won't handle it; I'm simply saying that **it won't handle it for a regimen of exercises over a longer period of time.** I do burpees daily and unless you're very fast, it's almost impossible to complete 10 reps in 20 seconds. And if you increase the sets to maybe 5, 20:10 will simply not be able to handle it *(if you want to prove me wrong, try it and see if you'll be able to complete that within that timeframe)*. Now imagine increasing the reps to 20; at some point, 20:10 won't work. And that's basically my point. **Increase the interval as you get stronger.**

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Checking my logs, I could do 8 in the first round at my best, dropping down to 4 by the last round. Getting to 8x8 would have been quite a challenge, so I definitely had room to grow. So, I guess my conveniently bolded advice would be: **try harder as you get more fit**.

Comment: @VPeric While that basically proved my point, all I can say is this: keep on improving. As long as that's your goal, everything will fall into place :). I hope you're still doing it as it's a great workout :).

Comment: -1 This answer is clearly uninformed about the realities of interval training, Tabata in particular.

Comment: @Zod Before questioning Tabata, you should research it AND try it. It's a KILLER workout. I work up to 30 minutes of 30/30 HIIT before I start doing Tabata. The reduced rest periods significantly increase the intensity of successive intervals.

Comment: The original tabata training was for a duration of **4 mins** and it's **not viable for all forms of cardio exercises.** More importantly though, **as long as what you're doing works for you, that's all that matters;** everything else is just noise :).